# ¿Como puedo Cambiar el Orden de las Variables de una Coleccion en Firebase?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, colecciones

Estoy creando una aplicacion en Ionic/Angular para la cual estoy intentando obtener los datos de una Coleccion de Firebase para posteriormente exportarlos a excel para la cual utilizo el siguiente codigo:

```
    this.db.collection('Usuarios').get().toPromise().then(querySnapshot =>{
            const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
     })
```

El Problema es que al revisar la constante data me muestra que me ordena cada uno de los registros en diferente orden como se observa a continuacion:

```
{"sede":"FUNZA","rol":"Admin","nombres":"Administrador ","email":"italcolapps@gmail.com","confirmPassword":"","password":"","cargo":"Administrador del Sistema","cedula":"9010467471","apellidos":"Italcol","telefono":"3005134302"}
{"apellidos":"Ovalle","cargo":"Analista de Datos","cedula":"1065138151","telefono":"3005134302","password":"","rol":"Operario","sede":"FUNZA","nombres":"Moises ","confirmPassword":"","email":"moissj@gmail.com"}
{"nombres":"Prueba","rol":"Operario","apellidos":"Prueba","telefono":"3191894949","cedula":"4894984984","email":"prueba@gmail.com","cargo":"Prueba","password":"","sede":"ECUADOR","confirmPassword":""}
```

La pregunta es como puedo hacer para cambiar el orden de las propiedades de cada documento o por lo menos obtener las propiedades en un mismo orden? deberia quedar algo mas o menos como esto:

```
 {"sede":"FUNZA","rol":"Admin","nombres":"Administrador ","email":"italcolapps@gmail.com"}
{"sede":"FUNZA","rol":"Operario","nombres":"Moises","email":"moissj@gmail.com"}
{"sede":"ECUADOR","rol":"Operario","nombres":"prueba","email":"prueba@gmail.com"}
```

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: ¿Cual es el campo por el cual quieres ordenar los documentos?

Comment: Pues veras especificamente el orden del campo puede ser cualquiera siempre que esten en el mismo orden lo que quiero es que al obtenerlos y guardarlos en una constante queden todos en el mismo orden por ejemplo:
{"sede":"FUNZA","rol":"Admin","nombres":"Administrador ","email":"italcolapps@gmail.com}
{"sede":"FUNZA","rol":"Operario","nombres":"Moises","email":"moises@gmail.com}
{"sede":"ECUADOR","rol":"Operario","nombres":"Prueba","email":"prueba@gmail.com}

en vez de la manera desordenada en que se estan obteniendo

Comment: Entonces tu pregunta va por el lado de el orden de las propiedades de cada documento, no de los documentos en sí dentro del arreglo? Por otro lado te voy a pedir que cuando compartas el contenido de la constante `data` lo hagas en forma de arreglo así evitamos confusiones innecesarias. A lo que me refiero es que tu constante `data` es un arreglo y la representación de su contenido debería ser algo como: `[ {"sede":"sede1","rol":"admin"},  {"sede":"sede2","rol":"admin"} ]`. Se entiende?

Comment: Exactamente lamento la confusion es solo que pense que con el ejemplo habia quedado claro pero la representacion del contenido deberia quedar tal cual como lo planteas

Comment: Entonces te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta para clarificar a qué te refieres con el orden y también corregir la representación de la variable. Puedes hacer click en [edit]

Comment: Vale ya lo edite gracias por la sugerencia